# CLJS Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: clojurescript, figwheel

I am writing a cljs library from scratch (i.e. without a leiningen template). Using `lein figwheel`, Figwheel successfully compiles my cljs into JS, but doesn't fully connect to my application because of the following three errors that show up in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at utils.cljs?rel=1627878774806:73
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at Function.cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$3 (async.cljs?rel=1627878780415:57)
    at cljs$core$async$chan (async.cljs?rel=1627878780415:45)
    at Function.cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$1 (async.cljs?rel=1627878780415:54)
    at cljs$core$async$chan (async.cljs?rel=1627878780415:45)
    at Function.cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$0 (async.cljs?rel=1627878780415:53)
    at cljs$core$async$chan (async.cljs?rel=1627878780415:45)
    at file_reloading.cljs?rel=1628044048652:338
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at Function.cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$3 (async.cljs?rel=1627878780415:57)
    at cljs$core$async$chan (async.cljs?rel=1627878780415:45)
    at Function.cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$1 (async.cljs?rel=1627878780415:54)
    at cljs$core$async$chan (async.cljs?rel=1627878780415:45)
    at Function.cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$0 (async.cljs?rel=1627878780415:53)
    at cljs$core$async$chan (async.cljs?rel=1627878780415:45)
    at figwheel$client$file_reloader_plugin (client.cljs?rel=1628044052054:150)
    at figwheel$client$add_plugins (client.cljs?rel=1628044052054:451)
    at client.cljs?rel=1628044052054:473
```

Here is my core.cljs:

```
(ns cljs-spotify-sdk.core)

(defn load-sdk []
  (let [script-id "spotifySDK"]
    (when-not (. js/document (getElementById script-id))
      (let [script (. js/document (createElement "script"))]
        (-> script (.-id) (set! script-id))
        (-> script (.-type) (set! "text/javascript"))
        (-> script (.-async) (set! true))
        (-> script (.-src) (set! "//sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js"))
        (let [first-js (-> js/document (.getElementsByTagName "script") (aget 0))
              parent (.-parentNode first-js)]
          (.insertBefore parent script first-js)))))
  (.log js/console "SDK script inserted"))
```

How can I resolve these errors?

Comment: Please share the source, that results in that error and how you run it.

Comment: I just added that information by editing the post.